# How can I identify the root cause and fix a query in Elasticsearch cluster that never returns a response

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

How can I identify the root cause and fix a query in Elasticsearch cluster that never returns a response.

I have an Elasticsearch cluster with Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana running on the same machine using Docker compose. The Elastic version is 8.3, and the cluster is used for logging. The index lifecycle management policy is set to rollover the index if it exceeds 40 GB in size, and the log retention period is set to one day. The machine has 2 VCPU and 8 GB RAM, and a 200 GB gp3 disk.

I make queries from the Kibana UI. While all queries work fast, one particular query never returns a response, especially when searching logs for application B combined with some text in the message field. The query is shown below and works fast for application A but not for application B:
One thing that I know is that the message field for application A are very large compared to my other applications.

Here is the query that I picked up from the Kibana UI

```
{
  "track_total_hits": false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": "*",
      "include_unmapped": "true"
    },
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
    }
  ],
  "size": 500,
  "version": true,
  "script_fields": {},
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "runtime_mappings": {},
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "message": "app is running"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "app_name": "A"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2023-04-05T11:15:16.781Z",
              "lte": "2023-04-05T11:30:16.781Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

The query fails on a very small time frame also.
How do I identify the root cause and fix the issue ?

I am not sure what to try here.

Comment: If the `message` field can be big, then running a `match_phrase` on it can result in query time outs (I guess you have `timed_out: true` in your response). Try adding `"terminate_after": n`, where `n` is a small number (like 10) and if you get results, you can increase it up to 500 divided by the number of your primary shards

Comment: I am making the query from the Kibana UI. I am not sure how this should be modified there. can you please indicate how that can be done. Also doing this via the console would not be beneficial as this cluster is a logging cluster and its important to see the results in Kibana.

Comment: Ok, if you're running the queries from Kibana, what kind of error do you see when you see the query failing?

Comment: I don't see an error. The query never returns till long until I close the browser. I just tested it and I haven't seen a response in 5 minutes. The circle near the elastic logo keeps on spinning.